# ı try to add firebase libary in build.gradle but ı cant see allproject ,buildscript

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here][1]

ı try to add firebase libary in build.gradle but ı cant see allproject ,buildscript
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxEsL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio has removed those tags from there. You need to add them in the `settings.gradle` file.[image]

Comment: dependencies {

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

  }

Comment: for example ı have a this line how can ı add this

Comment: add to app level build.gradle